# Joomla module position not appearing

Tags: joomla1.5

I have created a joomla template on localhost. It was working and all the module positions are displaying their respected modules. However, when I upload the website to a live server I found that jdoc: type="modules" code is not working at all. All other themes are working fine on the server.

Here is the link to my website.

http://www2.adcirrus.com/

Between
I am using XAMPP on my local machine with no extra configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You have to correct this, and see what happens (u missing a ">" sign):

```
<div class="lower-header" <jdoc:include type="modules" name="lower_header" style="xhtml" />
```

to this:

```
<div class="lower-header"> <jdoc:include type="modules" name="lower_header" style="xhtml" />
```

the div tag have to be closed.

And that "xhtml" style is defined?